# AutoRunning Upon Open Issue

Tags: vba, excel, autorun, email-notifications

First off, I'm not very savvy when it comes to programming in VBA. I've done a lot of programming in the past in Java, C++, C#, and a few others so I'm not completely new to programming in general.

My current issue is that I have an inventory list that I want a notification to be emailed from once a certain quantity has reached a certain value. The email notification is setup and working fine except when the worksheet is closed then reopened, the notification will be sent again if the value has not gone above what was previously set. For example, if the quantity is at or below 1, a notification will be emailed. If that quantity is not changed to 2+ before the worksheet is saved and closed, the next time the sheet is opened, the notification will be sent again.

I want to limit this so that only when the quantity is changed for the first time then the notification is sent.

Code below:

```
Public Function EmailNotification(model As String, color As String, cell1 As Range)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup

        If cell1.Value <= 1 Then

            'For Each cell In Columns("R").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                'If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
                    'LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value) = "yes" Then

                       Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                       On Error Resume Next
                       With OutMail
                           .To = "username@domain.com"
                           .Subject = "Excel Notification: Toner Renewal"
                           .Body = "Dear Team," & _
                               vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                               "Please prep an order for " & color & " toner for a Dell " & model & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                               "Quantity Remaining: " & cell1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                               "Notification Sent: " & Now() & " from " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName


                           .Send
                       End With
                       On Error GoTo 0
                       Set OutMail = Nothing
                   'End If
               'Next cell

        End If

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

---

cell1 is the quantity that gets checked in the function.

I'm not sure if there is a way to halt this AutoRun at the startup then allow it to run again whenever one of the quantities is changed.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would suggest using another column to keep track of when the email was sent and use the on worksheet change event to track when the quantity changes to reset that email column.

Comment: That's something I was thinking about doing. However, when I did cell.Value = XXXX, the cell doesn't get changed.

Comment: you can also set up another boolean argument that will be set to true when it runs after the quantied is changed (and not on startup) so it will not fire unless boolean is TRUE

Comment: Not knowing all the VB commands, how would I check to see if the cell was changed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a cell in your workbook (say `cell2`) and store a boolean to say if the email has already been sent once or not.

Your function would look something like this:

```
Public Function EmailNotification(model As String, color As String, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range)

  Dim notifSent As Boolean: notifSent = cell2.Value '<-- get the value of cell2
  If cell1.Value <= 1 And Not notifSent 'if quantity below threshold and no notification yet sent
      'you send the email for the first time...
      cell2.Value = True 'and you set this information in your cell
  ElseIf cell1.Value > 1 And notifSent 'if quantity above threshold and notification has been sent before
      cell2.Value = False 'reset notification to false
  End If
```

Comment: After putting this code into what I currently have, it still doesn't want to work. I put in some Debug.Print lines to see where it is getting hung-up and the function stops at the cell2.Value = True line. If notifSent is false, cell1 is <=1, and the above line is commented out, the email is then sent. Every time I've tried putting in a .Value = "some change", the function stops unless I put a On Error Resume Next in.

Comment: @Encl4v3 what do you mean "hung-up"? Do you have an error?

Comment: I input this code to check and see:
        On Error Resume Next
        cell2.Value = True 'and you set this information in your cell
        Debug.Print Error
The debug then shows:
Application-defined or object-defined error

Is this what you're looking for?

I meant hung-up by the function not continuing. It seems to just stop but not provide an error pop-up.

Comment: @Encl4v3, that error sounds like cell2 is not defined. How are you defining it before to pass it to the function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean by "How are you defining it before to pass it to the function?" . I put "FALSE" into the cell where cell2 is reading from. I didn't make any 'Dim's for cell2. I'm just new to the VB language.

Comment: @Encl4v3, well, if you don't declare/define any cell, it's normal you can't use it. In the version above of my function, I pass a "cell2 As Range" to your function as you pass the "cell1 As Range". I guess, before you call your function to send the notification, you say somewhere "cell1 = Range("A5")" (for example) and then pass cell1 along. You should do the same thing with cell2: choose a cell where storing your TRUE/FALSE about having already sent a notification, then set that cell2=Range("yourrange"), then call the function.

Comment: as of right now, no. I don't apply any changes to cell1 so I just pull the value to check it. In this case for my Function, I'm using your above code for the 4 arguments, Model, Color, Cell1, and Cell2. When I call this function in a cell it's currently =EmailNotification(B4,B6,D6,V6). From what you're saying that definitely sounds like the issue I just don't know where I'm supposed to be declaring/defining cell2. Is this supposed to be IN the function but BEFORE I start the IF for cell1.value AND NOT notifSent? If I am, I've tried doing that but the function errors out again.

Comment: @Encl4v3 if you're calling your function directly from the spreadsheet, then in the cell V6 you should just type a value of type "True/False" (in your Excel's language: if you're french you should write "Vrai/Faux", if you're italian you should write "Vero/Falso" etc.). You might want to write False if the notification hasn't been sent yet.

Comment: Alright, so that's what is currently in there. The function still does not want to permanently change the value of V6. I have it set to True so when I open the Excel sheet, a notification doesn't auto get sent. I only want it to get sent when a quantity changes for the first time. We can move to PMs if that helps.

Comment: @Encl4v3 that's the logic behind my code. The value of cell2 says True if notification was sent, False else. When you call your function, if the quantity is below 1 AND the notification has not been sent, the email is sent and the value of cell2 is set to True so that, next time, even if the quantity is still below 1, the mail is not sent. However, when the quantity gets up to 1 again and the notification was sent, the cell2 is set to False. Like that, when the quantity will be below 1 again, the notification will be re-sent.

Comment: Okay, that's what I grabbed from reading through it. The issue still stands that the value of cell2 is being read as False but when the email gets sent, cell2 does not get changed to True in the Excel spreadsheet (V6).

Comment: @Encl4v3 that's because a Function is not supposed to change the values of other spreadsheets. You will need a Sub for that. Why do you call your entire code as a function (instead, for example, of creating a Sub called on workbook open)?

Comment: Honestly because I didn't know what else to do. This is my first time really getting into VB. That was gonna be another question, if I'm even doing this the right way. I don't know what that would look like for a sub (or a bunch of subs) to do what I need to do.

Comment: Problem solved! Made this into a Worksheet_Change Sub. I can paste the code if requested. I ended up making a boolean cell for each quantity cell so that in case multiple quantities get changed in 1 session, multiple alerts will be sent. Works well but could probably be tidied up a bit since I mostly new to VBA. Thanks for the assistance!